# how to call a method in the Promise in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a Vue component:

```
import { someRequestMethod } from '@/api/requ'

...

methods: {
    testMethod() {
        someRequestMethod(someRequestData).then(function() {
            this.outMethod_01()
        }).then(function() {
            this.outMethod_02()
        })
    }

    outMethod_01() {
        console.log('I am an outer method 01.');
    }

    outMethod_02() {
        console.log('I am an outer method 02.');
    }
}
```

when I call `testMethod`, with a `Promise` response.
then I want to call `outMethod_01` if succeed, `outMethod_02` if got error.
but i got error `outMethod_01 is undefined` and `outMethod_02 is undefined`.

so how to call a outer method in the `Promise`?

Answer (score 7):

You should use arrow function syntax `(params) => {...code}` instead of `function(params) {...code}`. In arrow function `this` is inherited from the scope. In regular function, `this` is the function itself (it has its own scope).

You can learn more here: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

If you can't use ES6 syntax, you could do something like:

```
methods: {
    testMethod() {
        var self = this;
        someRequestMethod(someRequestData).then(function() {
            self.outMethod_01()
        }).then(function() {
            self.outMethod_02()
        })
    }

    outMethod_01() {
        console.log('I am an outer method 01.');
    }

    outMethod_02() {
        console.log('I am an outer method 02.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping the calls in anonymous functions you can hit two birds with one stone by using `bind()`:

```
  someRequestMethod(someRequestData)
    .then(this.outMethod_01.bind(this))
    .then(this.outMethod_02.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testMethod() {
    someRequestMethod(someRequestData).then(() => {
        this.outMethod_01()
    }).then(function() {
        this.outMethod_02()
    })
}
```

this works.

Comment: This is the perfect answer so fur, with vue and axios using the '.then(function(response) => {....' failed for me but changing to '.then((response) => {' as suggested worked like charm